# Как применить фильтр для JTextField?

Tags: java

Т.е мне нужно разрешить пользователю в текстовое полу только числа из промежутка от 40 до 100. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Для этой задачи лучше подойдет JSpinner, а если все же хотите JTextField, то обрабатывайте событие, например focusLost и в нем делайте проверку.

[Здесь представлено описание JSpinner](http://www.javadesktop.org/articles/Spinner/)